# How to reproduce google login form effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need a bit of help.
I'm trying to reproduce the google chrome user login page and i'm stucked (really stucked i don't even know where to start) with the input field of that form.

i tried inspecting chrome page but is quite difficult to understand how to reproduce the effect it has

let me explain my self with a little of code.

so i have my form with my inputs field (like shown under) when i click one of the field i want that the place holder come up like chrome do.

i really have no idea how to reproduce that kind of effect...
before click:
[not selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjNVQ.jpg)
after click:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v117A.jpg)

```html
<input type="text" name="user-name" placeholder="Username"></input>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
```

```css
input{
border:solid 1px #222;
}
input:focus{
border:solid 2px #ddb760;
}
```

Comment: It's not a real placeholder. They're just stacking text (usually a label) on top of the input and moving it on focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google manage to make it look like `placeholder`, but it is just a `div` with text that is moving hover and on top of the input.

This is pretty much how to do it.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var label = document.getElementById("label-text");

text.addEventListener("focusout", onfocusout);

function onfocusout(e) {
 if (text.value.length > 0) text.classList.add('not-empty');
 else text.classList.remove('not-empty');
}

// allow focus of the input even on click of div
label.onclick = function(e) {
 text.focus();
}
```

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

#text {
  padding: 10px;
  
  border: 1px solid black;  
  outline: none;
}

#label-text {
  padding: 0 5px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 5px;
  
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #999;
  
  transition: .2s;
}

#text:focus {
  border-color: blue;
}

#text:focus + #label-text {  
  color: blue;
}

#text:focus + #label-text, #text.not-empty + #label-text {
  top: -10px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<br><br>

<div class="input-group">
  <input id="text" type="text" onfocusout="" />
  <div id="label-text">Username</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

with css `transform` and `:placeholder-shown` pseudo class. Trick is, you have to add a placeholder(space as value) attribute to the inputs 
 - `placeholder=" "`.

```css
.g-input {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
.g-input label {
  background: white;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: transform 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), opacity 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  color: #ddd;
  font-family: arial;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: text;
}

.g-input input, .g-input textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.g-input.fill {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.g-input input:focus, .g-input textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #1873e8;
}

.g-input input:focus+label, .g-input input:not(:placeholder-shown)+label,
.g-input textarea:focus+label, .g-input textarea:not(:placeholder-shown)+label{
  transform: translateX(-3px) translateY(-15px);
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #1a73e8;
}
```

```html
<div class="g-input">
  <input type="text" id="user-name" name="user-name" placeholder=" ">
  <label for="user-name">Username</label>
</div>
<div class="g-input">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder=" ">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
</div>

<div class="g-input fill">
  <input type="text" id="user-name2" name="user-name2" placeholder=" ">
  <label for="user-name2">Username</label>
</div>
<div class="g-input fill">
  <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder=" ">
  <label for="password2">Password</label>
</div>

<div class="g-input fill">
  <textarea id="ta" name="ta" placeholder=" "></textarea>
  <label for="ta">Textarea</label>
</div>
```

Comment: nice example ! I am wondering how you are making a click on your label focusing directly your input.

Comment: I have just a problem with your answer if the field isn't required it doesn't work, i'd like not use js like @robinvrd in his answer, so there is a way to do so?

Comment: @GiovanniBianchetti the trick `required` + `:valid` is the only way to not use js here.

Comment: in that case @robinvrd your answer is the one i was looking for i have some fields that aren't required in my form :)

Comment: @robinvrd @Giovanni Bianchetti you can achieve it with `:placeholder-shown` pseudo selector. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this could help:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="user-name" placeholder="Username" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Username'">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Password'">
```

CSS:

```css
input {
  border:solid 1px #ddb760;
}

input:focus {
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/x9khyv71/